# `dist/` Folder Empty on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vite

#### Disclaimer

I just want to start this question by saying that I am a complete beginner to web dev.

This question might be stupid so thank you for looking at it and answering it.

#### Setup

I am on node version 16.15.1 and npm version 9.5.0. I created my project by running `$ npm create vite@latest`. I then choose Vue and Javascript. Other than npm complaining about "`deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead`" everything worked well.

I `cd`ed into the project and ran `$ npm install` and then `$ npm run build`. No errors or warnings occurred.

#### Problem

After this, I opened up `dist/index.html` and there was nothing except a blank page. `npm run dev` seems to work, but I can't find the final website anywhere.

I have previously tried again and again but I get the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Again, I want to thank anyone who takes the time to answer my question.

Edit:
I am trying to generate static HTML for use in something like Github Pages.

Comment: `npx vite preview` after `npm run build`?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you have seen as well as the source-code of `dist/index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a web server to see the build, you cant just open `dist/index.html` in a browser.

To view your build you can run `npx serve dist` from the root of your project.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `npx serve dist` works but I need static HTML because I am using github pages. Is there any way to get static HTML? Thanks again for taking the time to read and answer my question.

Comment: You can follow the Vite documentation [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages) on how to deploy to Github pages, its easy to follow.